# Basic differentiation of summation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, summation

According to my assignment:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w_i}\sum_i^d w_i x_i = x_i$$

But I am only able to arrive at:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w_i}\sum_i^d w_i x_i = \sum_i^dx_i$$

I would love an explanation..

Comment: $w_j $ is a constant wrt $w_i $ for all $j\neq i $

Comment: $$\frac{d w_{i}}{dw_{j}}=\delta^{i}_{j}$$

Comment: Ah, I got really confused due to subscript (i) beeing used both places

Comment: In the sum each $w_i$ is multiplied with $x_i$ separately, so when differentiating wrt $w_i$ any term which does not have that particular $x_i$ in it vanish. Sometimes easier to write $w_1 \cdot x_1 + w_2\cdot x_2 + \cdots + w_d\cdot x_d$

Comment: Wait yes it should be confusing because you are not supposed to use same variable names outside of loops as you have as loop variables ($i$ in this case). Also when doing computer programing that can be a major source of confusion.